# Cant pass variable from view to another view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i have a view that contains a WebView the idea is when i click on a link in that webview and the link is not from the same domain of the url i use, it will open another view that contains another webview and pass that url to it.

here my first view

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    var url = "http://someurl"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self

        let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView : UIWebView) {
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView : UIWebView) {

    }

    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest r: NSURLRequest, navigationType nt: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

        var url = webView.request?.URL.absoluteString

        if nt == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
            self.switchScreen(r)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func switchScreen(url: NSURLRequest) {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        let vc : UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("innerBrowser") as UIViewController
        vc.url = url
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



}
```

and then the second view

```
import UIKit

class InnerBrowserController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var innerBrowserView: UIWebView!

    var url:NSURLRequest?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //let requestURL = NSURL(string:url!)
        //let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

        self.innerBrowserView.loadRequest(url!)

    }

}
```

when i set the url in the second view it works just fine.

Comment: Where actually you stuck? Simple executing you second viewController method like [vc loadRequest:r] doesn't work when presenting new viewController?

Comment: vc doesn't have a loadRequest ..

Comment: i'm stuck at passing a url from a view to another

Comment: so just create method or variable to store request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things come across my mind.

First, you cast to `UIViewController`, instead of casting to `InnerBrowserController`. You could do it like :

```
let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("innerBrowser") as InnerBrowserController
```

The second thing is that it seems you never assign your `vc.url`, hence, you don't pass the value to the second view. You can do that like:

```
let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
vc.url = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
```

The former will work only if you cast your view controller loaded from storyboard into the `innerBrowserView`.

Maybe I missed something, but I think this will fix your problem.

Comment: i just didnt add this line to the question vc.url = url, i'll test with the cast you mentioned

Comment: I edited that line since its not string but NSURLRequest ( as the variable in the other controller expects) Swift won't let you assign that value without adequate cast